# Labels in xtable captions for crossreferencing in lyx

Tags: sweave, lyx, xtable

I am using pgfsweave with Lyx 1.6.8 and xtable.
providing table captions by

```
<<result=tex>>=
print(xtable(<dataframe>,caption="Here is my caption"))
@.
```

How can I insert a label into the table caption that I can crossreference in the text from the lyx>Insert>Cross-reference menu?

I have tried to insert>float>table and inserted
`print(xtable(<dataframe>,floating=FALSE))` and
`"Here is my caption"` in the Table caption inner frame
but this results in (literally):

```
[ﬂoat Table:
<...Table ...>
[Table 2: "Here is my caption" ] ]
```

Even a barefoot workaround to crossreference

```
<<result=tex>>=
print(xtable(<dataframe>,caption="Here is my caption",label = "tab:one"))
@
```

from an ERT-box would help.

Comment: I add code formatting to your question and answer.

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED:
Just use TWO arguments in the `xtable`-function call in the R-code:

```
xtable(<dataframe>
, caption = "My caption\\label{tab:MyTable1}"
,label="tab:MyTable1")
```

The `\\label{tab:MyTable1}` inside the caption is changed to
`\label{tab:MyTable1}` by R and then interpreted by LaTeX.

The argument `label="tab:MyTable1"` is ignored by R and therefore at your disposal to trick  Lyx into allowing for crossreferencing to the label table label.
Use Insert>label to insert the label `"tab:MyTable1"` (excluding the quotes) here.